# How to commit and push the subfolder .git to github from intellij IDEA?

Tags: git, github, push

When sharing a project on GitHub, the `.git` subfolder is not included in the repository. I would like to also include it.

Comment: Surprisingly legitimate question, but the answer is: don't

Answer (score 0):

Please do not attempt to push the .git subfolder, from IntelliJ Idea or by any other means. `.git` **is** your repository. Everything else you see is the local checkout, providing an editable picture of your current commit-to-be.

The entire history, configuration, and structure of your repo lives in `.git`. You don't need to "add" it to the repo. Any time you make a change, it goes into `.git`. Any time you push or pull, you are already transferring the relevant portions of `.git` to your remote.

The reason `.git` has a dot in front of its name is that it makes it semi-hidden on Unix-like systems. `ls` won't show it by default, and more experienced users will recognize it as a file intended to be used by the program, not directly by the user of git.

Don't feel bad though. This is a totally normal reflex for beginners, until you learn how things are arranged.

Comment: @JBNizet. Gotcha. I don't normally watch that show, but it's on my "eventually" list